# Fixed Values for Rows in a query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

Consider this SQL:

```
SELECT c1 AS C1, 
       1  AS NO 
FROM   t1 
WHERE  c1 = 'abc' 
UNION 
SELECT c1 AS C1, 
       2  AS NO 
FROM   t2 
ORDER  BY NO
```

as you may notice yourselves, the first select statement before union is just a bypass to add a new value to the list returned by the second query.

is there a way to not involve `t1` in the query? It is my feeling that it is unnecessary but am not able to do anything better with this query.

Result:

```
C1    |NO
---------------
abc   |1
def   |2
ghi   |2
jkl   |2
mno   |2
etc   |2
---------------
```

Comment: You are selecting the column `c1` in the first part though. How are you going to do that without `t1`?

Comment: `as you may notice yourselves, the first select statement before union is just a bypass to add a new value to the list returned by the second query.`  I don't think that `UNION` do this...

Comment: please show exactly what is the output result that you want and what do you want to eliminate

Comment: i am going to do this without `t1` as i am the one defining the value of `C1 ='c1'` in the where clause

Comment: @VineetVerma ok adding in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you add `1 AS NO`, you can add `'abc' AS C1` with:

```
SELECT 'abc' AS C1, 
        1 AS NO 
   FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT c1 AS C1, 
       2 AS NO 
   FROM t2 
ORDER BY NO;
```

Comment: cool i thought that not having a `FROM` clause might give error

Comment: You can select anything that's not in a table without using a from clause. So you can select static strings or environtment variables like current_timestamp, and you don't need to include a from.

Comment: I tried it on postgreSQL, no idea on Oracle, sorry.
In postgreSQL it works fine.

Comment: @MozenRath Use `from dual`. [Dual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table).

Comment: I googled a bit, and found that in Oracle you must add `FROM DUAL` when you want to perform a select "without" a FROM clause.

Comment: If you do not want an implicit distinct added to the list of C1 from t2, replace UNION with UNION ALL -- you can then avoid the ORDER BY as well

Comment: no i need the implicit distinct but good to know about union all